# How "fnServerData" works in jQuery datatable? To POST data to server using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using below code to send data to server and get the response.

```
  var currentSource = "my url";

  var oTable = $(pagerDivName).dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": aryJSONColTable,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "aaSorting": [[1, "desc"]],
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": currentSource, //this is my URL
                "data": aoData, // this is my post data
                "success": fnCallback  //currently i pass empty "", i don't require call back.
            });
        }


    });
```

I am getting only COLUMNS in the grid, but i can not get response from server. I get bad response as follow.

```
          {"Message":"InternalError","ErrorCode":"InternalError"}
```

What did i miss?

somebody help me understand how below line of code works?

```
             "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) { ....
              // what is sSource Here?
```

Note: Web API is working fine when i use pure Ajax call. it fails only when i send from datatable. But in this case i used :

```
         postData: JSON.stringify(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `InternalError` messages means your server is stuffing up somewhere. Check your server code.

Comment: no, as i said if i directly call server code using $ajax then it works fine. it fails only with dattables.

Comment: Ok, well I recommend upgrading your usage to Datatables 1.10, since it's way nicer and the docs are better. The docs for "somebody help me understand how below line of code works" is here http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnServerData